# CI/CD Implementation in WebSphere Liberty 19.0.0.8 server with Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, ejb, websphere-liberty

Am developing application using Maven it has EJB layer. I configured datasource in WebSphere Liberty server. All transaction can be handle by the server. Am using Jenkins to build a application. I would like to create CI/CD implementation. For that I tried add Junit test in application. but am unable to connect database while doing Jenkins build. Because there is no communication b/w server and Jenkins while doing build. How can I create Junit that handle database connection and EJB without Mock.?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution you could use here is an integration testing library called [MicroShed Testing](https://microshed.org/microshed-testing/). It is created for integration tests with JavaEE/MicroProfile app servers such as Liberty, and can be used to test your application with external resources running such as DBs.

MicroShed Testing is ideal if you are running your Liberty application inside of a Docker container. If you are running in Docker, you can easily write an integration test that looks something like this:

```java
@MicroShedTest
@SharedContainerConfig(AppContainerConfig.class)
public class DatabaseTest {

    @Inject
    public static MyJAXRSEndpoint personSvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetPerson() {
        Long bobId = personSvc.createPerson("Bob", 24);
        Person bob = personSvc.getPerson(bobId);
        assertEquals("Bob", bob.name);
        assertEquals(24, bob.age);
    }
}
```

To get this working, you can define your application topology in the class referenced by the `@SharedContainerConfig` annotation like this:

```java
public class AppContainerConfig implements SharedContainerConfiguration {

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>()
                    .withNetworkAliases("testpostgres")
                    .withDatabaseName("testdb");

    @Container
    public static MicroProfileApplication app = new MicroProfileApplication()
                    .withEnv("POSTGRES_HOSTNAME", "testpostgres")
                    .withEnv("POSTGRES_PORT", "5432")
                    .withAppContextRoot("/myservice");

    @Override
    public void startContainers() {
        postgres.start();
        app.start();
    }
}
```

The above code will do the following steps:
1) Build your application into a Docker container, using the Dockerfile in your repo
2) Start up the docker container for your app AND the postgresql database (or any other DB container you may need)
3) Wait for containers to be ready, then run tests that invoke HTTP requests on the running containers

I find this approach nice because it works the same way anywhere Docker is installed -- either locally on your machine or in your CI/CD pipeline.

For more info on MicroShed Testing, I recommend checking out the website here:
https://microshed.org/microshed-testing/ 
and especially the examples, which include a Liberty+Database example:
https://microshed.org/microshed-testing/features/99_Examples.html

Disclaimer: I work on Liberty and MicroShed Testing

Comment: Thank you for your response. Am using Jenkins to build and UrbanCode Deploy for deploy application. Can I achieve with microshed-testing.?